# How to manage triggers

Tags: database

How do you keep track of your triggers? 
If you have several triggers how do you make sure they are working properly? 
What about errors, is there any good ways to log them ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the disadvantages of triggers if that they tend to happen "silently".  The way to ensure they are happening, and executing correctly/successfully would be simply to view their ouput.  In other words, if you are expecting an `INSERT` in an audit table, just double check the trigger is doing that.  Or if you have an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, test it out to ensure that conditionally something doesn't get inserted/updated/deleted if it doesn't conform to the trigger flow (or so you think).

What you can also do is **run a trace**.  You don't have your RDBMS specified in your question, but if you are using SQL Server, then run SQL Server Profiler and see what is hitting the database.  Then you'll know for sure everything that is happening, including trigger execution.